# Cannot Install PIL using Pycharm

Tags: python, module, pip, pycharm, python-imaging-library

Hi I'am trying to install PIL using Pycharm. I am using pip 19.1.1

When I try to install PIL this error occurs

```
Collecting PIL

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

I believe this error is due to no version of PIL being specified in the version drop down menu. I cannot specify a version of PIL to install as there are no options in the drop down menu.

Comment: Do you really want to install `PIL` or did you mean `Pillow`? According to pypi the last version of PIL is from 2006.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+No+matching+distribution+found+for+PIL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using Pillow: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

It is a friendly fork of PIL.

You can install it with:

```
pip install Pillow
```